# x,y calculation producing 3,3 rather than 1,2

Tags: c#

Context: My exercise was to develop a c# program on the console (visual studio) where the user will write a x,y positions and the algorithm will find the final position (after different movement indications that will influence x and y).

The problem is that the results make no sensd. And I have no idea where and how I can fix it.

Indeed, here's an example of what suppose to happen on the console.
The user types this:

```
0,0
3
r
u
u
```

And the result that should happen would be this :

```
1,2
```

but what really happen is :

```
3,3
```

And the result vary. Sometimes it's right, sometimes false. Any ideas ?
Here's the code:

```
string ligne2; // THE USER WRITE X,Y 
ligne2 = Console.ReadLine();
string[] ligne2Num = ligne2.Split(',');

int x;  
int y;
x = int.Parse(ligne2Num[0]);
y = int.Parse(ligne2Num[1]);

//THE USER WRITE ON THE CONSOLE THE NUMBER OF MOVEMENT HE WANTS TO DO
int I;
I = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Dictionary<string, string> Instructions = new Dictionary<string, string>();

//THE USER WRITE THE MOVEMENTS -> r = right, u = up, l = left, d = down
int i;
for (i = 0; i < I; i++)
{
    Instructions.Add("d" + i, Console.ReadLine());
}

   
foreach (string item in Instructions.Values)
{
    if (Instructions.ContainsValue("u") || Instructions.ContainsValue("U"))
    {
        y++;
    }
    if (Instructions.ContainsValue("l") || Instructions.ContainsValue("L"))
    {
        x--;
    }
    if (Instructions.ContainsValue("r") || Instructions.ContainsValue("R"))
    {
        x++;
    }
    if (Instructions.ContainsValue("d") || Instructions.ContainsValue("D"))
    {
        y--;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(x + "," + y);
```

Comment: Don't you want something like `item == "u"` instead of `Instructions.ContainsValue("u")`? For all three iterations of the foreach loop, the instructions do contain both "u" and "r", so it makes sense that x == 3 and y == 3.

Comment: What is the command `3` supposed to do? I understand `0,0` as the staring position, and `u`, `d`, `l` ,`r` as directional commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at your `foreach` statement, then you are not using the value from `item`, which is already an indicator that something is not right.
if you don't use the value, then a normal for `loop` is better.  Although here, the `foreach` is actually fine we just need to ensure we use the value.

As you have 3 entries, then the loop will execute 3 times.  But because you are looking through the whole dictionary (`Instructions.ContainsValue`) for each iteration, then you will execute the increment/decrement statements for each iteration, so this is why you end up with `3,3`.

We can also simplify the if statements into a switch statement, and only check for the lowercase value.  So then we end up with the folllowing.

```
   foreach (string item in Instructions.Values)
   {
       switch(item.ToLower())
       {
           case "d": y--;
               break;
           case "u": y++;
               break;
           case "l": x--;
               break;
           case "r": x++;
               break;
        }
    }
```